# How to add buttons in material-ui data grid rows?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add buttons in each row of the material-ui data grid... But when I'm trying to do so, I see the output as follows (rather than the button it shows something like [object Object].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg3NL.png)

Below is my code:

```js
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
    { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", width: 130 },
    { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", width: 130 },
    {
      field: "age",
      headerName: "Age",
      type: "number",
      width: 90,
    },
    {
      field: "fullName",
      headerName: "Full name",
      description: "This column has a value getter and is not sortable.",
      sortable: false,
      width: 160,
      valueGetter: (params) =>
        `${params.getValue(params.id, "firstName") || ""} ${
          params.getValue(params.id, "lastName") || ""
        }`,
    },
    {
      field: "click",
      headerName: "Click",
      type: <button />,    /*this field stores the buttons*/
      width: 90,
    },
  ];
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      lastName: "Snow",
      firstName: "<a>hello</a>",
      age: 35,
      click: <button>Hello</button>,   /*given a button to first row*/
    },
    { id: 2, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Cersei", age: 42 },
    { id: 3, lastName: "Lannister", firstName: "Jaime", age: 45 },
    { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", age: 16 },
    { id: 5, lastName: "Targaryen", firstName: "Daenerys", age: null },
    { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, age: 150 },
    { id: 7, lastName: "Clifford", firstName: "Ferrara", age: 44 },
    { id: 8, lastName: "Frances", firstName: "Rossini", age: 36 },
    { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", age: 65 },
  ]);
  // setRows(

  // setRows(rows);
  // );
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const [arr, setArr] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  return (
    <>
      <p>you pressed {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: "50%" }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          checkboxSelection
        />
      </div>
      <table>
        {arr.map((n) => (
          <tr>${n}</tr>
        ))}
      </table>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          arr.push(4);
          console.log(arr);
          var t = [...rows, { id: 3 }];
          // rows.push({ lastName: "hello" });
          // setRows(t);
          setRows(t);
          console.log(rows);
          // document.title = arr;
          setArr(arr);
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Also, after the button is inserted, how can I reference the current index or id of the row inside the button, suppose if at every click of button I need to show an alert which displays the information such as id and firstname for that row... how can i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use render cell:

```
{
      field: "click",
      headerName: "Click",
      width: 90,
      renderCell: (params) => {
         // you will find row info in params
         <button>Click</button>
      }
    },
```

Comment: welcome, upvote and the right answer will be appreciated.